VMware on Ubuntu 24.04 Linux 6.8.0-38-generic throws an error while trying to open it
VMware was "successfully" i nstalled. Nevertheless, when I try and click on the app icon, the following prompt appears:

Before you can run VMware, several modules must be compiled and loaded into the running kernel
CANCEL or INSTALL

For which I click on INSTALL only to lead me to the following prompt:
Compiling and installing following kernel modules:
vmmon 
vmnet

The problem comes when the following error appears:
Unable to install all modules. See log /tmp/vmware-tr4v1s/vmware-9919.log for details. (Exit code 1)

Link to log file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wpGpfmwt338ktadP-DGJtPU6IcJrxs1L/view?usp=sharing

Test your links, please.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ALaKVMrqXTjmltCoe_eyeAVh6AHqPTIT/view?usp=drive_link

@user535733 If you're referring to dong something in the terminal, I'm lost here. A bit more context please?

There are two web pages that provided workable solutions for those on kernel 6.8.x:
https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2024/04/install-vmware-player-ubuntu/ [take note of the instruction regarding secured boot; need to disable before patching]
https://dimitar.me/how-to-fix-vmware-unable-to-install-all-modules-vmmon-vmnet/
Common to both solutions, is to download the patch relevant to the version of VMware workstation that you're using, from mkubecek's github repo. At the time of this post, the latest patch is for v17.5.1
If you encounter errors with the tar ball replacement method (failure in compiling patch with -Wmissing-prototypes issue), refer to the solution to this problem statement:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/773558/vmware-vmmon-vmnet-17-5-1-and-linux-kernel-6-8-0-wont-compile
I encountered -Wmissing-prototypes error when following the tarball swap method; the "modules: fix build with -Wmissing-prototypes" solved the vmmon and vmnet compile problem.
ADDENDUM:
If you're on secure boot, you may encounter the following error when you try setting up your guest OS:"Could not open /dev/vmmon:No such file or directory. Please make sure that the kernel module 'vmmon' is loaded."
When you encounter this rror and then run "sudo /etc/init.d/vmware restart", you notice that 'Virtual machine monitor' and 'Virtual ethernet' is not done.
As secure boot is enabled, unsigned drivers are not allowed to be loaded. To load "vmmon" and "vmnet", you'll need to sign these two modules by following the instructions here (both provide the same solution):
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53058681/vmware-on-linux-could-not-open-dev-vmmon/63510868
VMWare 15 Error on Ubuntu 18.4 - Could not open /dev/vmmon: No such file or directory

Thanks. The first link seemed to work. I also had to redo the whole process after updating VMware to the latest version, but deactivating secure boot on bios seemed to be the game changer here.
